# Guidance on solving a task using MVC pattern in PHP

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I'm working on a project in which I have to parse a file containing genealogical data (a family tree) and then produce a website to explore it. My thoughts are to build up a data structure in PHP of individuals, families, etc. And then present these.

MVC seems the best way forward, but I'm not exactly sure how to go about implementing a model that uses PHP objects in memory. All the MVC guides I've seen the model is a database.

Answer (score 1):

The Model in an MVC pattern isn't a database and involves much more than data access.  Rather, a database is commonly accessed through a Model layer when persistent data is required.  Accordingly, you could implement an MVC pattern without relying on a database.  The implementation details would vary depending on framework/etc. Having said that, if learning is a priority, I'd recommend reading more about MVC prior to using it without fully understanding its purpose.